# SharePoint REST API CAML Query error : “Every two elements in an array and properties of an object must be separated by commas."

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml, sharepoint-rest-api

While quering with the **CAML query** in the **SharePoint REST API** throws following error.

```
{ 
    "error": { 
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException", 
        "message": { 
            "lang": "en-US", 
            "value": "Invalid JSON. A comma character ',' was expected in scope 'Object'. Every two elements in an array and properties of an object must be separated by commas." 
        } 
    } 
}
```

***Request:***
../sites/POCs/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList2')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'2'} 
[image: Request Headers and request]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the **CAML** which is passing in the `GetItems` query. Simply you can replace *single quote* with **double quote**, further means that in CAML is XML based query language and you need to provide attributes within the double quotes.

Request **CAML** Sould be as follows;

```
../sites/POCs/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList2')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=***"ID"***></FieldRef><Value Type=***"Number"***>2</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'}
```